# Indesign CS6 Is it possible to make one really long page and use breaks to make it work as if it's multiple pages?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, forms, interaction

I'm having trouble using the show/hide feature in Indesign to effect elements across multiple pages (see my question on  the issue [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58144/indesign-cs6-how-to-show-and-hide-elements-on-multiple-pages)).  If I can't figure out how to make that work my next best solution will be to make one page that's about 75,000 pt long and use some type of feature to add breaks where the pages would normally be so the user will be able to follow along and jump back and forth between "pages" like any other multi page PDF.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

ok I just figured out this is indeed possible.  What I would need to do is just create some element to serve as a page break and bookmark it.  So when I make the "Next page" button I can just click "go to destination" and select the bookmark I want it to load to.